# Resize and add white borders so there is always the same picture size when uploading image in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm working with pictograms, I want to display all the pictograms the user have (grid list and grid tiles). The problem is that the aspect ratio of the pictograms changes a lot according to the pictogram.
[image: Screenshot of the web app: We can see that a high ratio aspect can hide the text and the cross]
For now, I use ng2-img-max in order to resize (but save the ratio) of the pictograms. I'm a total newbie in CSS but I tried some things (max-width: 80%.. Playing with this stuff...) But I think that the ideal would be to add white borders to pictograms in order to have a 300px*300px (for example)and then manage their display with ease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a great tutorial on responsive layouts with CSS grid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bam83Xv4VMA) that I have myself found it useul.

```
<div class="grid-container" fxFill>

  <div>
// WHATEVER YOU WANT INSIDE HERE -- TILE 1
  </div>

  <div>
// WHATEVER YOU WANT INSIDE HERE -- TILE 1
  </div>

  <div>
// WHATEVER YOU WANT INSIDE HERE -- TILE 1
  </div>

</div>
```

Now the SCSS for  that:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid; // displays in grid
  width: 100%; // useful to have the fill the container
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(12rem, 1fr)); 
  padding: 0px; // personal preference
  grid-column-gap: 30px; // personal preference
}
```

Now the most important part of that is the 'grid-template-columns` property. [You can read more about what different settings do here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns)

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to watch that video and see if it solve the problem !

Comment: Good luck, from my experience so far, this has been the most reliable way to get consistent, responsive grids regardless of the size and aspect ratios of the individual elements. With that grid you won't need ng2-img-max or any other form of processing for the images.